# Handling Dependencies from Unmanaged Native to Managed NET, Via C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, interop

I have two open code bases. The first, where the application starts is in unmanaged C++ (no /clr enabled). The second, that is a dll library, is managed .NET C# (.NET 6) and is opened as a plugin by the unmanaged code

I have complete control over these code bases except for these initial conditions (can't refactor the managed library as a COM object for instance and can't add /clr to the originating native app)
I want these two code bases to talk to one another. Additionally with some functions between them operating under time constraints, if that matters (passing video frame data from one to the other in real-time)

In achieving this, so far what we've done is implement a third C++/CLI project as an intermediary (/clr:netcore 6 enabled), that functions really well. We really like this because it works plenty fast for our use case and interop is simple to implement with import/export, entirely inside dev-environment, with full type enforcement throughout

The problem we are having is firing up C# NET from inside C++ results in the app searching around for all of NET's dependencies and failing to find them. And the only way of solving that, that we've found so far is deploying all of NET local to the application's running directory and obviously this isn't ideal

> Side note here, we did this by running a publish build on the managed
> library to collect together all of its dlls. So, on the one hand, we
> admit we haven't fully confirmed every single dll as required, **but**
> we have confirmed - by stepping through adding at least some dlls one by one -
> that the errors cite various .NET libraries, Accessability,
> System.Windows.Forms etc. I'm including this just for clarity of what
> we do and don't know at this point, but we figure that this shouldn't
> really be relevant because the managed app, when ran as the program
> entry-point finds all its dependencies as expected and we figure we're
> missing some kind of setting or hook needed to inform the native/CLI
> components of how to link into all the managed libraries' references,
> taking care of everything in one go
> Please also note that the projects see eachother inside the IDE just fine

**Given these initial project conditions, what is the simplest and most direct way to make the native app see the dependencies of the managed app, the same way in which the managed app sees them for itself when ran in isolation?**

Ideal candidate solutions should:

- Be as simple as possible. We're loosely expecting something like a
  project reference, build parameter or run-time environment variable
- Introduce as few layers of indirection as possible. There's already
  one layer via C++/CLI, which is a very transparent layer, with full
  type enforcement and native IDE integration
- Happen in-development-environment. Fiddling with O/S path variables
  isn't really solving the fundamental project visibility issue

Additional context of other interop solutions outside of these lines is fine but won't be accepted as final answers. That would include talk of COM objects, P/Invoke etc. Fine to talk about but would be considered messy and less than the ideal here

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/native-hosting.md

Comment: What particular error message are you running into, and during what operation (when the app loads the C++/CLI DLL, or after the C++/CLI DLL starts running and tries to load the C# assembly)?

Comment: Also, make sure that the .NET Framework versions match between the C++/CLI and C# projects.  C++/CLI hasn't been updated for the newer .NET Core and .NET 7+ runtimes, it still wants 4.x

Comment: @BenVoigt the app successfully loads throughout, as long as all the C# projects dependency assemblies (including NET) are dumped into the running directory. if we don't do that we get "LoadLibrary failed for '<dependency>.dll': The specified module could not be found." errors as soon as code execution enters any NET calls

Comment: @HansPassant going to need time to go through this but at a glance, this seems like this introduces a new layer of indirection? if correct, this would be less than ideal. especially given that the problem can already be solved in-file-system whilst preserving all of the transparency that c++/cli offers

Comment: @Sick of Paper: Can you test with a C++/CLI assembly that doesn't have any dependencies on any non-standard files?  Just `ref struct X { int foo() { return 42; } };` plus your native plugin exports?  If that fails, try with an equally minimal native plugin DLL built with the C++ compiler (and no `/clr`).  I mention this because it's far more common to have problems with the C++ runtime DLLs than .NET

Comment: @BenVoigt have now ran a test plugin that calls through c++ plugin, CLI intermediary and into bare bones C# library with no dependencies and it runs just fine. have also updated the question with some additional context (just regarding /clr settings, as the native project doesn't have /clr which is probably a weird situation. and also a note on how we figured out our current - less than ideal - deployment situation). hopefully this is clearer where we're at